# Are there any free version control hosting applications I can host myself?

Tags: git, svn, version-control, mercurial, versioning

I'm looking for some server software that would allow me to manage git, mercurial or even subversion repositories on my own server (I'm not picky, I can live with any of those). The perfect thing would be of course a private downloadable version of github or bitbucket server application...

The main feature I need is a web interface to create and manage some version control repositories located on my server and control users access to any of those resources (preferably without giving those users shell access).

Thanks.

Comment: Why wouldn't you use any of the hosted services such as Github, Bitbucket or Beanstalk? Not trolling, just curious.

Comment: I want to host my projects on my own servers. There can be many reasons:
1. NDA signed with clients
2. faster 1Gbit access to repositories
3. being obsesed with privacy :)
4. costs of using commercial services

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try [gitlab](http://www.gitlabhq.com). Its webinterface has some similar features as Github, like Pull (or Merge) requests, commit overview etc. and Gitlab is free.

Comment: This might actually be what I was looking for, I'll try it right away. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Both Mercurial and git provide web interfaces of their own that are server-suitable.  Mercurials is called 'hgweb' and git's is 'gitweb'.  They're free and relatively easily configured.  If you want something more bitbucket / github like (pull requests, teams, bug trackers, etc.) Then you want either [Rhodecode](http://rhodecode.org/) (for Mercurial) or [gitorious](http://gitorious.org/) for git.  Personally I just use hgweb: http://ry4an.org/hg

Comment: hgweb and gitweb are nice, but you can't create or manage repositories with them.

Answer (score -1):

Sure it's costly, but you can download Github : https://enterprise.github.com/

AFAIK, it's exactly the same application than runs on Github, but on your own server.

Comment: OP is looking for a free solution.

Comment: I ended up paying for **GitLab Enterprise Edition** anyway, but it's nothing compared to what I'd have to pay for github enterprise.